# Flux integral of paraboloid on x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Been trying to answer this problem for hours. Here is the text of the problem:

Let $W$ be the solid bounded by the paraboloid $x = y^2 + z^2$ and the plane $x = 4$. Let $F = 5x\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k}$

(a) Let $S_1$ be the surface of the paraboloid oriented in the negative $x$ direction. Find the flux of the vector field through the surface $S_1$.

I am stuck with the integral over the paraboloid of $y^2 + z^2 - y - z$. If that is right, my problem is in trying to write a double integral of that in cylindrical coordinates. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Use $\LaTeX{}$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can take you part way.

You'll need the normal unit vector to the surface, which is found through the gradient.  If $g(x, y, z) = y^2 + z^2 - x = 0$, then

$$\hat{n}(x, y, z) = \frac{\vec\nabla g(x, y, z)}{|\vec\nabla g(x, y, z)|} = \frac{-\hat{x} + 2y \hat{y} + 2z \hat{z}}{\sqrt{1+4y^2+4z^2}}.$$

Then the flux density is

$$\hat{n}\centerdot \vec{F} = \frac{-5x + 2y^2 + 2z^2}{\sqrt{1+4y^2+4z^2}}.$$

From here, you might notice that this is in terms of $y^2 + z^2 = r^2$ which is the distance from the $x$ axis:

$$\hat{n}\centerdot \vec{F} = \frac{-5x + 2r^2}{\sqrt{1+4r^2}}.$$

Comment: Sounds true, but I am supposed to set the problem up as a function of two variables. The integral is in the form $$\vec{F}(x, y, f(x,y))\centerdot(-F_x,-F_y,1) dx dy$$
So I am assuming I need to switch some of the variables. The second part is defined as the cross product of $R_x$ and $R_y$, if that helps.

Comment: Sure.  You can change variables earlier than I did.  No harm in that.  The dot product is a function of two variables now, though.  Here is (almost) exactly your problem [worked out](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/flux/flux.html), by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Given the choice of the vector field and the shape of the enclosed volume, it looks to me like this problem may have been intended for the application of the Divergence Theorem, $ \ \iint_S \ \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ \ dS \ = \ \ \iiint_V \ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} \ \ dV \ $  .

The divergence of the vector field in this problem is

$$ \ \nabla  \cdot  \langle \ 5x , y , z \ \rangle \ = \ 5 \ + \ 1 \ + \ 1 \ = \ 7 \ \ . $$

[image]

The enclosed volume is a paraboloid with circular cross-section oriented with its symmetry axis on the $ \ x-$ axis , truncated by the plane $ \ x \ = \ 4 \ $ .  Its volume can be found by integrating infinitesimal cross-sectional "slices" along the $ \ x-$ axis, which are circular with radii $ \ r \ = \ \sqrt{y^2 + z^2} \ = \ \sqrt{x} \ $ :

$$ V_{par} \ = \ \int_0^4 \ \pi \ [ \ r(x) \ ]^2 \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ \pi \ \int_0^4 \ x \ \ dx \ = \ \pi \ \cdot \ \frac{1}{2}  \cdot  4^2 \ = \ 8 \pi \ \ .  $$

The Divergence Theorem thus tells us that the *total* flux through the entire surface on this "capped" paraboloid is $ \ 7 \ \cdot \ V_{par} \ = \ 56 \pi \ $ .

This total comprises the flux through the surface of the truncated paraboloid itself (the quantity sought) and the flux through the disk in the plane $ \ x \ = \ 4 \ $ , which is centered on $ \ (4, 0, 0) \ $ and has radius $ \ \sqrt{4} \ = \ 2 \ $ .  The normal to this disk is $ \ \mathbf{n} \ = \ \mathbf{i} \ $ , so the surface integral for the flux of $ \ \mathbf{F} \ $ through it is

$$ \iint_D \ \langle \ 5x, y, z \ \rangle \vert_{x=4} \ \cdot \ \mathbf{i} \ \ dS \ \ = \ \ \iint_D \ 20 \ \ dS \ \ = \ 20 \ \cdot \ \pi \cdot 2^2 \ = \ 80 \pi \ \ . $$

The flux through the truncated paraboloid's surface, designated $ \ S_1 \ $ , is thus $ \ 56 \pi \ - \ 80 \pi \ = \ -24 \ \pi \ $ .  The negative result is reasonable, since the field vectors have positive $ -x \ $ components in the positive $ -x \ $ "half-space", and the orientation of the paraboloid surface is in the *negative* $ \ x-$ direction.  (The $ y- $ and $ z- $ components of the flux simply cancel out "quadrant-by-quadrant" over the surface, owing to its axial symmetry.)